# Rails Console Inserting Data into a Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is what I did

```
Customer.all

  Customer Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Customer id: 1, name: "Judy Ngai", created_at: "2013-08-13 18:50:02", updated_at: "2013-08-13 18:50:02", phone_number: nil>]>
```

then

```
judy = Customer.find(1) 
insertdata = judy.phone_number = "1234567890"
insertdata.save!
or 
insertdata.save
```

gives me

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `save' for "6265607524":String
NoMethodError: undefined method `save!' for "6265607524":String
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
judy = Customer.find(1) 
judy.phone_number = "1234567890"
judy.save!
```

Comment: Remeber you can accept the answer, so that, other people who are looking for answers may be helped by this question! :)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use .update_attributes like so:

```
judy = Customer.find(1)
judy.update_attributes(:phone_number, "1234567890")
```

If you use update_attributes it performs validation as well (which `=`/`save` do not do). For a list of different way to assign attributes check out [5 Ways to set Attributes in ActiveRecord](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/2011/06/28/5-ways-to-set-attributes-in-activerecord/)

Comment: just want to point out, the update_attributes bypass validations and will save the record regardless into the database.